# Use CartoDB Map as Tile Service

Tags: carto

I have a custom CartoDB map that uses data I have uploaded and styled. The map works perfectly and I would like to use it as a basemap in a different application. Is there any way to use this map as a tile service?

I realize that I could use CartoDB.js in the external application but I do not control that resource and have simply been asked to provide a tile server as input downstream. I'm not certain but I believe the downstream application is using Google Maps API. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use our [Maps API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html) to get the tiles in an xyz format. It's possible in several languages as you only need to instantiate the map with a POST, but here is how to do that through JavaScript:

```
var mapconfig = {
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "layers": [{
    "type": "cartodb",
    "options": {
      "cartocss_version": "2.1.1",
      "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: #FFF; }",
      "sql": "select * from european_countries_e"
    }
  }]
}

$.ajax({
  crossOrigin: true,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: 'https://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v1/map',
  data: JSON.stringify(mapconfig),
  success: function(data) {
    var templateUrl = 'https://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/' + data.layergroupid + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    console.log(templateUrl);
  }
})
```

That code is in the [Anonymous Maps section](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#anonymous-maps) of the documentation.